# Changing thread priority using JNI call in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, java-native-interface

I am trying to write an a small test where i am trying to change a java thread's priority to set it to real time property on my Scientific Linux box.

I figured that this needs to be done using a JNI call, as using Thread.MAX_PRIORITY or Thread.MIN_PRIORITY, will never map it to real time priorities.

I'm stumped at how can i get access to my java thread from my native code. The following is my java program:

```
public class ThreadPriorityTest implements Runnable {

    public static int numThreads;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("***Java: Changing thread priorities");
        changePriority();
    }

    public static synchronized native void changePriority();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: ThreadPriorityTest <num_of_threads>");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        numThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        for(int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadPriorityTest());
            t.start();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
How can i get access to my java thread from my native code?
```

When you make the jump from Java to native via JNI, there is no thread switching.  Once you are in native code, the current thread is the same OS thread as was executing before the jump.  Do what ever you want to the current thread while in native code.  If you need to test to see if your changes persisted, jump back to native after JNI returns to run any change checkers.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Since JDK 1.5, there's `long Thread#getId()` method which can be the one you seek for.</strike> To check, compare result returned by this method with the `nid` (native id) from generated thread dump (dump can be produced by `kill -3 java_pid`).

**UPDATE** Seems `getId()` returns some other id internal to JVM and not connected with OS.

Though, not sure if changing thread priority behind JVM back is the good idea. There's some Real-Time extension for Java which might be what you looking for.